# Ruby on Rails and DataTables buttons don't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatable

I am using Ruby on Rails and DataTables (jquery-datatables-rails 3.3.0)

It works fine but i can't add buttons and toolbar to my table:

```
<table class='table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered display' id="tasks">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In my .coffee file:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#tasks').dataTable
    bJQueryUI: true
    dom: "Bfrtip"
    buttons: ["create"]
    scrollX: true
    paging: false
    ordering: false
```

But there is no create button on my table. Other features like: scrollX: true work fine

Can anybody help me?

My application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/extras/dataTables.responsive
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.foundation
//= require dataTables/extras/dataTables.tableTools
//= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

My application.css.scss:

```
*= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
 *= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.foundation
 *= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
 *= require dataTables/extras/dataTables.responsive
 *= require dataTables/extras/dataTables.tableTools
 */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the correct code should be:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#tasks').dataTable
    bJQueryUI: true
    dom: "Bfrtip"
    buttons: [{
       text: "create"
       action: (e, dt, node, config) ->
         alert("Button clicked")
         return
    }]
    scrollX: true
    paging: false
    ordering: false
```

See [Custom buttons](http://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/custom) for more information.

Also Buttons extension requires extra CSS/JS files, see [Download - Buttons](http://datatables.net/download/release#Buttons).

Comment: Hi, thx for your replay and link, but it doesn't work for me ((( 
But other datatables features work fine (like paging, scrolling etc) Also, there are no errors in js console

Comment: @D.Rakov, also Buttons extension requires extra CSS/JS files, see [Buttons](http://datatables.net/download/release#Buttons).

Comment: Ok, and the last step - how to import it to my rails project?

Comment: Btw it works! so thx for help! And can i somehow change style for this button? or change it position? how can i assign class to this button to apply styles in my css?

Comment: for example i need to set class for my button = 'btn-link'